# Yii: design-by-contract with PHPUnit 3.7

Tags: php, yii, namespaces, phpunit, design-by-contract

I am using the yii framework and phpunit. I can run phpunit test.

But I want to add asserts in my controller like it is described [here](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-driven-development.html). I think the class

```
 BankAccount
```

is no test. So there must be a way to use the asserts not in tests.

If I call an assert like this in my controller, which is no test:

```
 PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue(false);
```

I get

```
currentPath\PHPUnit_Framework_Assert.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The file exists in my pear\phpunit directory.

So how can I use PHPUnit for design-by-contract?
Or is there no way to add asserts like this for design-by-contract?

Ps: I am using namespaces

Comment: Would you kindly tell us how you're running your tests? The Definite Guide to Yii has an [entire chapter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.overview) dedicated to that topic.

Comment: Hi i edited my question. But I execute the unit test on command line. But the `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue(false);` is not in my unit test. It is in one of my controllers.

Comment: Well, it doesn't belong there in the first place.

Comment: Why? It enables design-by-contract style.

Comment: Ah, scrap that. I got distracted and fell back t the way I test controllers.

Comment: I've been trying for an hour now without satisfiable results, sorry :-/ If you're in for a not-so-quick hack: You can declare all required classes and interfaces in the [class map](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#importing-classes). But it really should be a question of beating Yii's autoloader into submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36320-phpunit-not-working-with-yii-ctestcase-phpunit-autoload-not-found/) I found the solution for my problem. 
Here is the code to enable Design-By-Contract asserts of PHPUnit in Yii Controllers and Helper Classes.

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```